# Boundedness of $\int_a^b e^{iF(x)} dx$ for $F''(x) \ge r > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, proof-explanation, upper-lower-bounds

**My question is** regarding the **last sentence of Lemma 4.4.** of Titchmarsh's book *The Theory of the Riemann Zeta-Function*:

[image]

First I approached by taking three intervals as the text has done but for new $\delta$: $(a,2c-\delta)$, $(2c-\delta,\delta)$ and $(\delta, b)$ but after replacing $\delta = 2 r^{-\frac12}$ I could not get the bound $8 r^{-\frac12}$. Then I took two intervals $(a,c)$ and $(c,b)$ and by use of WolframAlpha I found out that in order to get the mentioned upper bound, $c>b$ must hold which is impossible. So how to prove Eq. 4.4.1 for $c<a+\delta$ or $c>b-\delta$?

Comment: I'm very confused: why do you want to use $(2c - \delta, \delta)$? And what does that even mean---won't your $\delta$ be quite small, likely of no particular reason to $2c$, so this interval is empty..?

Comment: Anyway: the analogous partition is the one already suggested in the proof: $(a, a+\delta)$ and $(a+\delta, b)$.

Comment: @JakobStreipel, $\delta=2r^{-\frac12}$ is fixed and not considered arbitrarily small. When $\delta > c$ then I took $\delta'=\delta -c$ and repeat the proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a\leq c<a+\delta$. You take $I_2=\int_a^{c+\delta}$ and $I_3=\int_{c+\delta}^b$. Now we still have $\vert I_2\vert\leq2\delta$ and on $I_3$ we still have $(x-c)\geq\delta$. (No $I_1$ here, just named them so they match with the other case.)

If $F'$ doesn't vanish and is positive (negative is handled similarly) take $I_2=\int_a^{a+\delta}$ and $I_3=\int_{a+\delta}^b$ so $\vert I_2\vert\leq\delta$ and on $I_3$ we have
$$F'(x)-F'(a)=\int_a^xF''(t)dt\geq r(x-a)\geq r\delta$$
so
$$F'(x)\geq r\delta+F'(a)$$
where $F'(a)>0$ so
$$\vert I_3\vert\leq 4/(r\delta+F'(a))\leq4/(r\delta).$$

Comment: $c+\delta$ or $a+\delta$ for upperbound in $I_2$? for $a+\delta$, $I_2 \le 2\delta$ ..

Comment: $c+\delta$, I forgot the case when $F'$ doesn't vanish, I will add that.

Comment: @Ali Added the case.

Comment: Lower bound for $I_3$ is $a+\delta$ for the case $F'(c) \ne 0$ and you took it $a$ later

Comment: @Ali It's not a typo. We have $a+\delta\leq x\leq b$. We are integrating the second derivative from $a$ to $x$ in the second case (where $F'$ doesn't vanish).

Comment: There would actually be one more case when $F'$ is negative but that is handled the same way.

Comment: Yes I can do that, thanks a lot :)